# Inverting the choice of interface implementer for serialization purposes

Tags: c#, implementation

I have a method which goes off via HTTP grabs some data as Json and deserializes it before passing the actual objects back to the caller, here is the header

```
public IServiceResponse<IEnumerable<ISession>> 
       GetAllBySubscriptionAndApp(string subscriptionId, 
                                  string appId)
```

Since I really don't care about any of the implementation details for the above interfaces my response statement looks like so.

```
var httpResponse = 
_httpClient.GetResponse<IServiceResponse<IEnumerable<ISession>>>(request, 
                                                                 _serializer);
```

Eagle eyed readers will notice that this will throw an exception because the serializer provided would not know enough about the interfaces to rehydrate the objects requested.

- **So my question is**

Given the above, what is the cleanest way for the caller to provide me with the concrete implementations I need to make my serialization work.